# Nested list objects with AutoValue/Gson fails with NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, gson, auto-value

I'm trying to use a JSON object to convert to a Java object (build with AutoValue) using Gson. The JSON object looks like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Nutella Pie",
    "ingredients": [
        {
            "quantity": 2,
            "measure": "CUP",
            "ingredient": "Graham Cracker crumbs"
        },
        ...
    ],
    "steps": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "shortDescription": "Finish filling prep"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

So the Java class (built with AutoValue) looks like:

```java
@AutoValue
public abstract class Recipe {
    @SerializedName("id")
    abstract int id();
    @SerializedName("name")
    abstract String name();
    @SerializedName("ingredients")
    abstract List<Ingredient> ingredients();
    @SerializedName("steps")
    abstract List<Step> steps();

    public static TypeAdapter<Recipe> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
        return new AutoValue_Recipe.GsonTypeAdapter(gson);
    }
}
```

The `create` method in the `TypeAdapterFactory` is:

```java
public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
    Class<? super T> rawType = type.getRawType();

    if (rawType.equals(Ingredient.class)) {
        return (TypeAdapter<T>) Ingredient.typeAdapter(gson);
    }
    if (rawType.equals(Recipe.class)) {
        return (TypeAdapter<T>) Recipe.typeAdapter(gson);
    }
    if (rawType.equals(Step.class)) {
        return (TypeAdapter<T>) Step.typeAdapter(gson);
    }

    return null;
}
```

However, I'm having the error:

> NoSuchMethodError: No static method getParameterized

This `getParameterized` is a `GsonTypeAdapter` method, and apparently is not implemented.

If I change the JSON and the Java classes to a nested object instead of a nested object list, **it works fine**.

I don't know what is going on. Any ideas?

EDIT: 
I made some progress. Acording to the AutoValue GSON Extension  [docs](https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-gson):

> To have support for fields with generic parameters (eg. List) you need to upgrade your Gson dependency to at least 2.8.0, which introduces the helper TypeToken.getParameterized() see Gson Changelog.

This way, my code to generate the Type adapter is:

```
public static <Ingredient,Step> TypeAdapter<Recipe<Ingredient,Step>> typeAdapter(Gson gson,
                  TypeToken<? extends Recipe<Ingredient,Step>> typeToken) {
    return new AutoValue_Recipe.GsonTypeAdapter(gson,typeToken);
}
```

However, Im having a problem using that on the TypeAdapterFactory, since it has to return a `TypeAdapter<T>`, not a `TypeAdapter<Recipe<Ingredient,Step>>`. Tried casting, but no success.

What do I do? Add a new TypeAdapterFactory?

Answer (score 3):

> `NoSuchMethodError: No static method getParameterized`

I'm assuming you're using `com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.4.6`, but you have an older Gson version prior to 2.8.0. You're getting the exception because the AutoValue generator uses Gson 2.8.0 under the hood, and Gson 2.8.0 introduced `TypeToken.getParameterized` (see commit [9414b9b3b61d59474a274aab21193391e5b97e52](https://github.com/google/gson/commit/9414b9b3b61d59474a274aab21193391e5b97e52)). And at the runtime JVM expects *your* Gson to provide the `TypeToken.getParameterized` method. Since you seem to have an older Gson version, it throws the error.

There's also a note on Gson 2.8.0 in the auto-value-gson [documentation](https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-gson#download):

> You will also need a normal runtime dependency for gson itself.
>
> `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'`

If you're using Apache Maven, just make sure that you have the latest Gson:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This should work. If you cannot upgrade Gson for whatever reason, try to downgrade the AutoValue Gson generator.

Comment: Actually I do have those libraries up to date.

Comment: @DavidPena You seem you don't. You have to track down your dependencies graph either via your build tool (in Maven: effective POM) or via JVM `java` runner by enabling loaded classes log (once you spot `TypeToken.class` you can just grep it for `getParameterized` -- I'm almost sure it doesn't have the method).

Comment: I'm using :

   `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    provided 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2'
    apt         "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2"
    provided 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.4.6'
    apt 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:0.4.6'`

Comment: I did an edit, and now the `getParameterized()` is not the issue

Comment: @DavidPena It's strange. The runtime clearly states that it cannot resolve the static method, and the result artifact might have something wrong. After the build is completed, check out the build directory for the `TypeToken.class` (by the way, how many `TypeToken.class` are there?) and just grep it (or them) for `getParameterized`.

Comment: @DavidPena Or (I remember I have removed the `android` tag from your question due to irrelevancy) just convert the result `dex` file back to a JAR or class files and just decompile `com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.class` to be finally sure.